# Create dummy variable based on if df1 rowdate is between two dates in df2 and df1 class match df2 class in r

Tags: r, date

I have two dataframes. df1 with several hundred thousand rows each indicating a parliamentary speech. These have columns that indicate the date of the speech, the party, speaker etc.

df1 looks like this:

```
date         speechnumber                speaker party party.facts.id chair terms   parliament iso3country year pyear
1 1997-10-07            3   Poul Nyrup Rasmussen     S            379 FALSE 18662 DK-Folketing         DNK 1997     1
2 1997-10-09            3            Torben Lund     S            379 FALSE  2865 DK-Folketing         DNK 1997     1
3 1997-10-09            5             Frank Aaen    EL           1527 FALSE   159 DK-Folketing         DNK 1997     1
4 1997-10-09            6         Pia Kjærsgaard    DF           1022 FALSE   195 DK-Folketing         DNK 1997     1
5 1997-10-09            7 Kristian Thulesen Dahl    DF           1022 FALSE   202 DK-Folketing         DNK 1997     1
6 1997-10-09           10         Jette Gottlieb    EL           1527 FALSE   179 DK-Folketing         DNK 1997     1
```

Then I have created another one (df2) where I have specified which parties formed government at what times. I have made this into long format (not sure whether this is best), where 1 indicates that party x was in government in the period from "start_date" to "end_date".

df2 looks like this:

```
    start_date   end_date party values
1  1996-12-30 1998-03-23    RV      1
2  1998-03-23 2001-11-27    RV      1
3  2001-11-27 2005-02-18    RV      0
4  2005-02-18 2007-11-23    RV      0
5  2007-11-23 2009-04-05    RV      0
6  2009-04-05 2011-10-03    RV      0
7  2011-10-03 2014-02-03    RV      1
8  2014-02-03 2015-06-28    RV      1
9  2015-06-28 2016-11-28    RV      0
10 2016-11-28 2019-06-27    RV      0
11 2019-06-27 2020-10-27    RV      0
12 1996-12-30 1998-03-23     S      1
13 1998-03-23 2001-11-27     S      1
14 2001-11-27 2005-02-18     S      0
15 2005-02-18 2007-11-23     S      0
16 2007-11-23 2009-04-05     S      0
17 2009-04-05 2011-10-03     S      0
18 2011-10-03 2014-02-03     S      1
19 2014-02-03 2015-06-28     S      1
20 2015-06-28 2016-11-28     S      0
21 2016-11-28 2019-06-27     S      0
22 2019-06-27 2020-10-27     S      1
23 1996-12-30 1998-03-23     V      0
24 1998-03-23 2001-11-27     V      0
25 2001-11-27 2005-02-18     V      1
26 2005-02-18 2007-11-23     V      1
27 2007-11-23 2009-04-05     V      1
28 2009-04-05 2011-10-03     V      1
29 2011-10-03 2014-02-03     V      0
30 2014-02-03 2015-06-28     V      0
31 2015-06-28 2016-11-28     V      1
32 2016-11-28 2019-06-27     V      1
33 2019-06-27 2020-10-27     V      0
34 1996-12-30 1998-03-23    KF      0
35 1998-03-23 2001-11-27    KF      0
36 2001-11-27 2005-02-18    KF      1
37 2005-02-18 2007-11-23    KF      1
38 2007-11-23 2009-04-05    KF      1
39 2009-04-05 2011-10-03    KF      1
40 2011-10-03 2014-02-03    KF      0
41 2014-02-03 2015-06-28    KF      0
42 2015-06-28 2016-11-28    KF      0
43 2016-11-28 2019-06-27    KF      1
44 2019-06-27 2020-10-27    KF      0
45 1996-12-30 1998-03-23    SF      0
46 1998-03-23 2001-11-27    SF      0
47 2001-11-27 2005-02-18    SF      0
48 2005-02-18 2007-11-23    SF      0
49 2007-11-23 2009-04-05    SF      0
50 2009-04-05 2011-10-03    SF      0
51 2011-10-03 2014-02-03    SF      1
52 2014-02-03 2015-06-28    SF      0
53 2015-06-28 2016-11-28    SF      0
54 2016-11-28 2019-06-27    SF      0
55 2019-06-27 2020-10-27    SF      0
56 1996-12-30 1998-03-23    LA      0
57 1998-03-23 2001-11-27    LA      0
58 2001-11-27 2005-02-18    LA      0
59 2005-02-18 2007-11-23    LA      0
60 2007-11-23 2009-04-05    LA      0
61 2009-04-05 2011-10-03    LA      0
62 2011-10-03 2014-02-03    LA      0
63 2014-02-03 2015-06-28    LA      0
64 2015-06-28 2016-11-28    LA      0
65 2016-11-28 2019-06-27    LA      1
66 2019-06-27 2020-10-27    LA      0
```

What I want is to create a dummy variable in df1 indicating whether party x was in government at the time of the speech. I have tried so many different ways but I cannot seem to figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: welcome to SO. please provide sample data pasting the result of `dput(df1)`, or `dput(head(df1))` when too large

Comment: meanwhile: looks like a 'basic' non-equi data.table join.

Comment: You mean this? (I removed some unnecessary columns - party and date is the most relevant for this task I believe. Here it is:

structure(list(date = c("1997-10-07", "1997-10-09", "1997-10-09", 
"1997-10-09", "1997-10-09", "1997-10-09"), speaker = c("Poul Nyrup Rasmussen", 
"Torben Lund", "Frank Aaen", "Pia Kjærsgaard", "Kristian Thulesen Dahl", 
"Jette Gottlieb"), party = c("S", "S", "EL", "DF", "DF", "EL"
), year = c(1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997), pyear = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
# set dates to actual date-format (if not already)
df1[, date := as.Date(date)]
df2[, start_date := as.Date(start_date)]
df2[, end_date := as.Date(end_date)]
# initialise the 'ingov' column to "no"
df1[, ingov := "no"]
df1[df2[values == 1,], 
    ingov := "yes", 
    on = .(party, date >= start_date, date < end_date)]
#          date                speaker party year pyear ingov
# 1: 1997-10-07   Poul Nyrup Rasmussen     S 1997     1   yes
# 2: 1997-10-09            Torben Lund     S 1997     1   yes
# 3: 1997-10-09             Frank Aaen    EL 1997     1    no
# 4: 1997-10-09         Pia Kjærsgaard    DF 1997     1    no
# 5: 1997-10-09 Kristian Thulesen Dahl    DF 1997     1    no
# 6: 1997-10-09         Jette Gottlieb    EL 1997     1    no
```